# allocates memory for a 2D array

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I'm allocating memory for a 2D array I think I'm doing it good, but when I at the memory it seems
to be different that what I wrote.

```
int size = 4;
table = (int**)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    table[i] = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
}
```

But when I look in the debugger, after I add all the elements of a 4X4 2D array.
It seems like I have more than 4 columns. I just add int in a regular way

```
table[i][j] = num;
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank!

EDIT: code of adding the int

```
int lineCounter = 0;
char line[200];
while (fgets(line, 200, fr) != NULL)
{  
    i = 0;
    char* split;
    int num;
    split = strtok(line, " ");
    sscanf(split, "%d", &num);

    table[lineCounter][i] = num;
    i++;
    for (i ; i < size; i++)
    {
        int num;
        split = strtok(NULL, " ");
        sscanf(split, "%d", &num);
        table[lineCounter][i] = num;
    }
    lineCounter++;
}
```

Comment: This looks good assuming you have `int **table`. Do you mean while inputting values to this 2D array you see more inputs being asked even after entering 4*4?

Comment: I have int** table. yea I see more inputs. it's preplexing

Comment: Can you show that code how you are inputting values to this array?

Comment: How exactly does it "seem like you have more than 4 columns"?

Comment: In this 2D array case, you may be seeing the elements that are the pointers to the 2nd dimension, remember that when you allocate an array this way, each of table[n], is actually a pointer, and will not hold one of your actual data elements.

Comment: added the 2D array filling

Comment: It still isn't clear exactly what problem you see. What do you expect the code to do, and what happens instead?

Comment: I ran the code and it looks good. Just I fetched input from `stdin`, I see you are reading from a file (if not mistaken) Can you show how your file looks?

Comment: later on in the code, when I pass the table from function to function, the values are not correct, and I feel it might because what I see here

Comment: 2 6 9 2
2 5 2 1
2 2 7 3
5 1 7 3  \n between each 4 numbers, can't figure out how to show it in the comment

Comment: @Mumfordwiz Please add your file contents to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   int j,i;
   int **table;
   int lineCounter = 0;
   char line[200];
   int size = 4;
   table = (int**)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    table[i] = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
}

while (fgets(line, 200, stdin) != NULL)
{  
    i = 0;
    char* split;
    int num;
    split = strtok(line, " ");
    sscanf(split, "%d", &num);

    table[lineCounter][i] = num;
    i++;
    for (; i < size; i++)
    {
        int num;
        split = strtok(NULL, " ");
        sscanf(split, "%d", &num);
        table[lineCounter][i] = num;
    }
    lineCounter++;
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
  printf("%d ",table[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and let you know

Comment: It works here... but if I sent the table to another function it doesn't work the for loop prints other stuff

Comment: Then there is problem with that part and you should ask a separate question for it